# How can Pyparsing match a counted array without discarding complex count expressions?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am looking at the input format for this [ACM problem](http://www.karrels.org/Ed/ACM/96/ftrellis.html), specifically:

> An NTA description is given by the number of states `n` followed by the number of accepting states on one line separated by whitespace. The `n × n` transition table follows in row-major order; each transition string is given on a separate line.

(Ignore the rest, it's not relevant.)

So for example:

```
3 1
a
a
c
ca
a
b
c
b
a
```

This means that the 9 (3²) lines following the first line are the transitions. In my code I need to retain both the 3 value and the 1 value, as well as a list of the 9 transitions. Ideally I'd like an expression that gives me:

- 3
- 1
- `['ab', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'ab', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'ab']`

My first thought was to try a `countedArray()`-based expression:

```py
from pyparsing import pyparsing_common, Word, alphas, countedArray

table_start = pyparsing_common.integer*2
table_start.addParseAction(lambda toks: toks[0]**2)
table_transitions = countedArray(Word(alphas), table_start)
```

However `countedArray()` suppresses the count expression, which means that I lose the value of 1 (the number of accepting states), and can only get the 3 back by taking the square root of the length of the resulting list.

I am not too concerned about full parsing for this problem, since the ACM problems let you assume that input will be properly formatted. So I could easily use a simpler expression and plain Python manipulation on the results. But I'm learning Pyparsing, and would like to know if this is possible in a straightforward way using that library (especially since I do encounter similar grammars in real projects that I would like to use Pyparsing to simplify).

Answer (score 1):

It is something of a hack, but if you expand the parse action on `table_start` to also set a parse action on `table_transitions`, you can add your accepting states as a named result on `table_transitions`:

```
def replace_count(toks):
    table_transitions.setParseAction(lambda t: t.__setitem__('num_accepting_states', toks[1]))
    toks[0] *= toks[0]
table_start.addParseAction(replace_count)

result = table_transitions.parseString(data)
print(result[0])
print(result.num_accepting_states)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'a', 'c', 'ca', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']
1
```

Answer (score 1):

This compelled me to learn how to use the `Forward()` feature of PyParsing:

```py
from pyparsing import pyparsing_common, Word, Group, Forward

import string

table_transitions = Forward()

def table_start_action(toks):
    num_states = toks[0]
    num_transitions = num_states**2
    table_transitions << Group(
        Word(string.ascii_lowercase[0:num_states])*num_transitions
    )

table_start = pyparsing_common.integer*2
table_start.addParseAction(table_start_action)

table_full = table_start + table_transitions

print(table_full.parseString("""
3 1
a
a
c
ca
a
b
c
b
a
"""))
```

This has the added benefit that I can constrain the transition table matching to include only the valid characters (the first `N` lowercase ASCII characters).

Comment: Nice way to constrain the allowed transition characters.